# Heroku node app prepending route to static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have been using heroku to host a node app. I declare my js/css/images in a public directory.

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
app.set('views',process.env.PWD + '/views');
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

I have tried __dirname instead of process.cwd(), both work the same. Anyway, in this app, I have two routes that I render:

```
app.get('/challenge', function(req, res){
  res.render('challenge');
});

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
  res.render('dashboard');
});
```

So in my views directory, I have challenge.ejs and dashboard.ejs. Both files have css and js includes, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When I run my app on localhost, both of my routes render correctly, and find this js file, however, when I push my app to heroku, only the dashboard app renders this file path correctly. The challenge route prepends "challenge" to the url when trying to find this js file, and as such, the js file cannot be found.

What I mean by this, is that when I go to myapp.com/dashboard, it loads myapp.com/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js,

yet when I go to myapp.com/challenge, it tries to load myapp.com/challenge/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js, which does not exist.

I am confused to why it would work find on localhost, but when deployed it does not. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried everything I could think of to no avail.

EDIT:
I also get this behavior when I try to add a parameter to any url path

```
app.get('/challenge/:my_param',  function(req, res){
  res.render('challenge');
});
```

EDIT AGAIN:
I can get around this by adding the "prepending text" to render the public directory, but I feel like I'm cheating...

```
app.use("/challenge", express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'))
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically how the file paths are getting resolved through your localhost vs Heroku. The fix should be easy with paths relative to the root.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried adding ./ before I posted the question; it still yields the same results.

Comment: I've never experienced this behavior, sounds like something else may be going on.